# Is it possible to construct $GF(4)$ with two different multiplication operations mod n and mod m as "addition" and "multiplication"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I found that it's possible to construct multiplication and addition tables for $GF(2)$ and $GF(3)$ in that way, but I still can't find ones for $GF(4)$. Is it possible at all?

$GF(2)$ can be constructed with elements $\{21, 7\}$ and operations $* \bmod42$ and $* \bmod28$

$GF(2)$ multiplication:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\ * \bmod42 & 21 & 7  \\ 
\hline
21 & 21 & 21  \\ 
7 & 21 & 7  \\ 
\end{array}

$GF(2)$ addition:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\ * \bmod28 & 21 & 7  \\ 
\hline
21 & 21 & 7  \\ 
7 & 7 & 21  \\ 
\end{array}

$GF(3)$ can be constructed with elements $\{10, 16, 4\}$ and operations $* \bmod30$ and $* \bmod18$

$GF(3)$ multiplication:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ * \bmod30 & 10 & 16 & 4    \\ 
\hline
10 & 10 & 10 & 10   \\ 
16 & 10 & 16 & 4\\
4  & 10 & 4 & 16\\ 
\end{array}

$GF(3)$ addition:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ * \bmod 18 & 10 & 16 & 4    \\ 
\hline
10 & 10 & 16 & 4   \\ 
16 & 16 & 4 & 10\\
4  & 4 & 10 & 16\\ 
\end{array}

---

[Edit]

Adding the following for clarity because users well versed in algebra can make mistakes here.

> Judging from the OP's examples and comments, mod should be *the binary mod*. In other words, $ab\bmod A$ is the remainder of the product $ab$ when divided by a positive integer $A$. This translates to the usual congruence only when both moduli are larger than all the elements of the "field", JL

[/Edit]

Comment: The additive group of $GF(4)$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of (coprime to $8$) residue classes $\{1,3,5,7\}$ of integers modulo $8$. Both are isomorphic to the Klein Four. Similarly the multiplicative group of $GF(4)$ is cyclic of order three, and isomorphic to the multiplicative group of quadratic residues modulo $7$, i.e. $\{1,2,4\}$. But I'm not sure whether that is what you are asking?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, I'm asking for explicit construction of algebraic structure with numbers as elements and two operations, multiplication mod n and multiplication mod m, that is, as a whole, isomorphic to GF(4).

Comment: This question needs more attention. A construction and a non-existence proof are both eligible for the bounty. I do confess that I also want to advertise [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive).

Comment: Basically we need a set of four positive integers $F$ and two moduli, call them $A$ and $M$. All the elements of $F$ should be smaller than both $A$ and $M$. Then $F$ needs to closed under multiplication modulo both $A$ and $M$. Furthermore, modulo $A$ the resulting 4x4 multiplication table should be isomorphic to that of the Klein four. Thus an element $Z\in F$ is specified as the neutral element of "addition", and we have $ZX\equiv X\mod A$ for all $X\in F$. Then $Z$ must be the multiplicative zero, so $ZX\equiv Z\mod M$ for all $X\in F$.

Comment: (cont'd)  And the multiplication of $F\setminus\{Z\}$ modulo $M$ must look like that of a cyclic group of order three.

Comment: The task is to give an example of $F$, $A$ and $M$ meeting all the requirements, or to prove that such a construction is impossible.

Comment: An obstacle easy to overlook is that we really need the set $F$ to be closed under the **remainders** of the products modulo $A$ and $M$. It is trivial to get congruences with respect to a small modulus by applying the CRT.

Comment: In other words, I would have solved the problem ages ago, if CRT-lifting the sets modulo $8$ and $7$ from my first comment to residue classes modulo $56$ would solve the problem.

Comment: In case anybody wonders about doing a brute force attempt: it shows no solution for $GF(4)$ with multiplication mod $\lt188 \; \times$ addition mod $\lt 300$. Similarly, $GF(5)$ has no solution for multiplication mod $\lt 133 \; \times$ addition mod $\lt 100$. (Why those strange figures? Because I just had to stop my PC and leave. :-)).

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Please consider describing your search heuristic as an answer (at least if you think it is at all generalizable). The two moduli likely need to have a lot of small factors (but most only to the first power), at least that's what I concluded when thinking about this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, but no, this was just a brute force attempt, i.e. testing all possibilities, without any intelligence in that.

Answer (score 6):

Choosing $n$ distinct primes $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ such that $p |q_i-1$, letting $k = \prod_{i=1}^n q_i$, you can embed $(\Bbb{F}_{p^n},+)$ into $(\Bbb{Z}/k \Bbb{Z},\times)$.

Taking one more distinct prime $\ell\equiv 1\bmod p^n-1$ you can embed $(\Bbb{F}_{p^n},\times)$ into $(\Bbb{Z}/\ell\Bbb{Z},\times)$

This way you are mapping each element $a\in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ to a pair of residue classes $b\bmod k$ and $c\bmod \ell $. You can represent this pair of residue classes by an integer $f(a)<k\ell$ such that $f(a)\equiv b\bmod k, f(a)\equiv c\bmod \ell$.

You'll get that $f(a+a') \equiv f(a)f(a')\bmod k,f(aa') \equiv f(a)f(a')\bmod \ell$ which is (I think) what you are asking for.

---

For $p^n=4$ you can take $q_1=3,q_2=5, \ell = 7$,

$\Bbb{F}_4 = \Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1) = \{0,1,x,1+x\}$,

$f(0) \equiv 1\mod 15,f(0) \equiv 0\mod 7$,
$f(1) \equiv -1\mod 3,f(1) \equiv 1\mod 5, f(1) \equiv 1\mod 7$,
$f(x) \equiv 1\mod 3,f(x) \equiv -1\mod 5, f(x) \equiv 2\mod 7$,
$f(1+x) \equiv -1\mod 3,f(1+x) \equiv -1\mod 5, f(1+x) \equiv 4\mod 7$.

Comment: A problem here is that the natural numbers $f(a)$ need to be smaller than $k$, if multiplication modulo $k$ is one of the operations. Like in the OP's construction of $\Bbb{F}_3$ as $f(0)=10, f(1)=16$, $f(2)=4$ all the integers are less than both $18$ and $30$. If you think this is not a problem, please exhibit the four integers and the two moduli.

Comment: Or, phrased differently. Congruence $f(a+a')\equiv f(a)f(a')\pmod k$ is not enough. We need $f(a+a')$ to be **the remainder** of $f(a)f(a')$ modulo $k$ et cetera.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen slightly useless overcomplication but I agree it makes the problem more interesting

Comment: Not what I hoped to see, but the voters like it enough.